# ImageView rotates only once (Android)

Tags: android, button, rotation, imageview

I have a refresh button which I want to rotate until the geo-location is fetched.
The problem is it only rotates one cycles and stops.

**refresh_button_rotate.xml** :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <set>
        <rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:duration="1000"
            android:fromDegrees="0"
            android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
            android:pivotX="50%"
            android:pivotY="50%"
            android:toDegrees="360" />
    </set>
```

**MainFragment** :

```
refreshGeo.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Animation rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation( mContext, R.anim.refresh_button_rotate );
        rotation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
        rotation.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
        refreshGeo.startAnimation(rotation);
```

I also tried the other method :

```
   RotateAnimation anim = new RotateAnimation(0f, 350f, 15f, 15f);
   anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
   anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
   anim.setDuration(700);
   final ImageView splash = refreshGeo;
   splash.startAnimation(anim);
```

It does rotate the image nonstop , but it rotates it from the upper-left corner of the view..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Signature of RotateAnimation constructor you used
RotateAnimation(float fromDegrees, float toDegrees, float pivotX, float pivotY)

if need to fix pivotX, pivotY as per your requirement. i.e. if you want to rotate from center than use(width/2, height/2) for (pivotX, pivotY).

Comment: in case of first method change android:repeatCount="-1" in anim xml file.